# Calendar/datepicker popup not working on safari

Tags: 8, javascript, datetime

Below is the date type form field I have in some form which renders on chrome correctly.

```
$form['date']['air_date'] = array (
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('Air Date:'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => !empty($arr['air_date']) ? $arr['air_date'] : '',
);
```

[image]

But the same code gives me following error in console of safari browser and displays **textfield** instead of **calendar** -

> TypeError: `$context.find('input[data-drupal-date-format]').once is not a function. (In '$context.find('input[data-drupal-date-format]').once('datePicker')', '$context.find('input[data-drupal-date-format]').once' is undefined)`

Comment: Is the line of code in the error code you wrote?

Comment: Drupal gives me the above TypeError in console of safari browse

Comment: Did you write this code: `$context.find('input[data-drupal-date-format]').once('datePicker')`?

Comment: No, this code is rendering from core files as I have used date form api..

Comment: If you remove the code you showed,does the error remain?

Comment: If I removed the form field having type => date then the field will not render and the issue will not rise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below workaround helped me to achieve working date-picker in all browser.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      if ($('.form-date').prop('type') != "date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
        document.write('<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
        document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
        document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n')
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
        $('.form-date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
      })
    </script>
```

Also I have added custom placeholder to the date field as safari displaying text-field instead of date field.
The typeError still exist in console but the above solution works for me in safari and other borwsers.